# Android: Adding validation to ensure a user can only enter numbers

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

In my app I am taking answers from a user for a mathematical game. Once the answer is entered the next question is displayed etc. 
Currently if the question is answered and a letter or a blank answer is entered by mistake the app crashes. 
I want for the app to just not take the user's answer if it is invalid and to keep displaying the question until a valid answer (number) is given.

Current code:

```
// sets text view equal to what is entered in editText
        final String entry = answer.getText().toString();
        // convert from string value to int
        int a = Integer.parseInt(entry); //

        // setting the user answer equal to the correct part of results array
        results[questionNumber - 1] = a;

        // If user answer is equal to correct answer then increase score
        if (a == correctAnswer[questionNumber - 1]) {
            score++;
            correctNoise.start();
            imageRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbsup);
        }else{

            incorrectNoise.start();
            imageRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbsdown);

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add `android:inputType="number"` to your EditText xml View. If you want to check it in code, this will check if a String is numeric:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
{  
  try  
  {  
    double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}
```

Source: [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java)

Comment: I have added the android:inputTpe="number" to the xml but it still allows the user to enter a none-numberic and then the program crashes

Comment: @RNI2013  What type of view are you setting it on?

Answer (score 1):

You should enforce the `InputType` of the `EditText`. This will make the numbers-only keyboard display. For example, to do this in *XML*:

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

or from code:

```
answer.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

Finally, just make sure the input is not empty:

```
CharSequence seq = answer.getText();
if (seq == null)
    return;
String s = seq.toString().trim();
if (s.length() == 0)
    return;
int a = Integer.parseInt(s);
//TODO use a, the valid integer response.
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer.parseInt() can throw a NumberFormatException.

You might try wrapping it like this, and then handling the exception by rejecting the user's answer:

```
try {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(entry);
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    // do something to handle the error
}
```

You can also ask the Android keyboard to show numbers using:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

on your EditText

Answer (score -1):

```
// sets text view equal to what is entered in editText

    if(answer.getText()!=null) {
    final String entry = answer.getText().toString();
    // convert from string value to int
    int a = Integer.parseInt(entry); //

    // setting the user answer equal to the correct part of results array
    results[questionNumber - 1] = a;

    // If user answer is equal to correct answer then increase score
    if (a == correctAnswer[questionNumber - 1]) {
        score++;
        correctNoise.start();
        imageRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbsup);
    }else{

        incorrectNoise.start();
        imageRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbsdown);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to ensure that user entered number first you can use

```
answer.setinputtype(inputtype.number);
```

and the second to write a function to check the value is  number

```
public static boolean tryParseInt(String value )  
    {  
         try  
         {  
             Integer.parseInt(value);  
             return true;  
          } catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
          {  
              return false;  
          }  
    }
```